# how to usewindows service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to use windows service in asp.net 3,5

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? What service? What is this service doing? Is it listening on specific port? Protocol?

Comment: You want to use a existing one or create one?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but I guess you are asking how to communicate with a Windows service from ASP.NET? I asume you are writing both the Windows service and the ASP.NET application?

I'd recommend [Microsoft Message Queing (MSMQ)](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx). This will let you send a message from ASP.NET, and have the Windows service pick up messages from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Look into .Net Remoting.

Your service can expose an object that can then be interacted with by other applications.